# Use image as theme for a page in mvc

Tags: css, asp.net-mvc-4

Currently i am running one mvc application where for one page i have to use one image as theme. I tried googling many things but non of theme worked for me.

I got one example from internet where one image used as theme like below:

```css
.intro {
 max-width:100%;
 height:auto;
 position:relative;
 background: url(~/Content/Images/1.jpg) no-repeat bottom-center;
   background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

```html
<body>
  <section id="intro" class="intro img-fluid img-responsive">
    </section>
 </body>
```

This was working fine with html page but the same i used in my one of the view that is not working.

Need someone help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using background-image instead. Also check that you have access to the image and add some content to the html for the background to be visible.

```
.intro {
    max-width: 100%;
    height: auto;
    position: relative;
    background-image: url(http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/paper.gif);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: bottom center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
}
```

In your Html body

```
<section id="intro" class="intro img-fluid img-responsive">
    <article>
        <div>Article1</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>Article2</div>
    </article>
    <article>
        <div>Article3</div>
    </article>
</section>
```

Comment: Thanks derloopkat, Your solution worked for me. I am marking it as answer.